# Como configurar o Laravel no heroku?

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, heroku

Saudação para todos,

Coloquei um projeto Laravel no Heroku, e conseguir configurar o bando de dados com o meu projeto Laravel, ou seje, conseguir migrar o banco de dados utilizando os comando do php no heroku, conseguir efetuar as configurações de forma correta para ele ter acesso ao banco de dados, mas algo errado está acontecendo, parece que ele não está reconhecendo a pasta public, mas eu criei o arquivo
 chamada Procfile e coloquei nesse arquivo isso abaixo;

```
web: vendor/bin/heroku-php-apache2 public/
```

Isso foi para ele reconhecer a pasta public, mas parece que não adiantou muito porque está aparecendo isso no navegador:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que será que pode acontecido?

==================================================

Essa é a estrutura do meu projeto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Gostaria de fazer um depilou la também mais sempre da erro. Como que vc fez. Tem algum tudo que vc fez que vc possa me passar?

Comment: desculpe, não entendi a pergunta.

Comment: Gostaria de aprender a fazer deploy no heroku como o Laravel. Como você fez? Você tem algo ai pra mim passar para eu poder aprender?

Comment: @NatanMelo deixa eu terminar de resolver meu problema que depois eu coloco como eu fiz aqui nesta postagem.

Comment: @wladyband, Fechado então. Vou torcer pra que as pessoas ai possam te ajudar.

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer poderia por favor me dizer onde fica está pasta public_htm? Pois eu não encontro ela aqui no meu projeto.

Comment: @DarleiFernandoZillmer Eu criei o projeto usando o composer, talvez esteja criando a estrutura de forma diferente por causa da versão, mas eu fiz uma atualização da minha postagem e gostaria que desse uma olhada, eu não encontrei esse arquivo index.php

Comment: @NatanMelo  foi assim 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=47B5tq9ZdW8

Comment: @NatanMelo esse aqui também 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dd1DPmVoGUg

Comment: blz eu vou assistir aqui muito obg.